# How do you find out the current size of an SQLDB instance in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

How do you know the current size of an SQLDB? Normally with DB2 I would check how much diskspace there is left to understand if the database is starting to get full. But as I don't have access to the file system I would like to know what the recommended alternative method is.

Best Regards

W

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in routine that might be able to help you:

```
CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, -1)
```

You can see more information about the routine on the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0011863.html).  The routine above would return something like this, for example:

```
 Value of output parameters
 --------------------------
 Parameter Name  : SNAPSHOTTIMESTAMP
 Parameter Value : 2004-02-29-18.31.55.178000

 Parameter Name  : DATABASESIZE
 Parameter Value : 22302720

 Parameter Name  : DATABASECAPACITY
 Parameter Value : 4684793856

 Return Status = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the SQLDB usage details by clicking the **Profile Settings** icon in the upper-right corner of the Bluemix user interface and selecting **Account -> Usage Details**. If you expand **Service Charges**, you should see your db instance listed with a $$ figure denoted.  On the right, you can expand the twistie and you should be able to see your current usage in GBs.